# Этимология слова "медицина"

Tags: этимология

Этимология слова "медицина" в источниках неправильно указана.

Comment: О каких источниках речь?

Answer (score 3):

***Медицина*** - Впервые у Петра I; см. Смирнов 192. Через польск. mеdусуnа или непосредственно из лат. medic–na (ars) от medicus, mеdеоr "**лечу, пользую**". (По словарю ***Фасмера***)
**Там же**:
***Медик***, Ближайшая этимология: Первонач. в знач. "цирюльник" и "врач", у Головина, 1705 г.; см. Христиани 46. Заимств. через польск. mеdуk (Христиани, там же; Смирнов 192) или прямо из лат. medicus (откуда и нем. Мedikus, с XVII в.; см. Шульц--Баслер 2, 94); см. Преобр. I, 519. Страницы: 2,590
 ***Медикамент***, Ближайшая этимология: Начиная с Уст. морск. 1720 г.; см. Смирнов 191 и сл. Через нем. Мedikament (с ХV в.; см. Шульц--Баслер 2, 94) из лат. medicamentum. Страницы: 2,590

Answer (score 0):

Слышала и такую версию : мадад е Сина -помощь Сины (Абу Али ибн Сина, Авиценна, величайший ученый и медик, на трудах которого держалась медицина в Европе вплоть до 18-19 века.)

Answer (score -3):

Значение слова Медицина произошла от персидского языка. слова Мед на персидском языке означает Наука. Цина это имя известного медика проживающий в период 12 века. Ибн Сина еще в 12 веку сделал первую операцию по опендециту. Медицина - Наука Сины.

Comment: Вот уж не знал, что Ибн Сина создал свою науку и что есть науки, названные по имени автора :))))